# Commit mutation from another file nuxt

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

How can I in `user.js` call mutation from `whoToFollow.js` called `reset` ? Is it even possible ? Heres my code:

```
async logOut({commit}) {
    this.$cookies.remove('token');
    commit('set_token', null);
    commit('whoToFollow/reset');
    this.$router.push('/sign-in');
},
```

But it doesn't work I get this error:

`unknown local mutation type: whoToFollow/reset, global type: user/whoToFollow/reset`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to call mutations from other stores directly. You are just missing the option '{root: true}', which is needed for namespaced modules.

I would recommend calling an action in the other store first though, which then again calls the mutations to stay true to the Vuex pattern. Actions -> Mutations

```
async logOut({commit, dispatch}) {
   this.$cookies.remove('token');
   commit('set_token', null);
   // in the reset action you can then call the commit
   dispatch('whoToFollow/reset', payloadHere, { root: true })
   this.$router.push('/sign-in');
},
```

I advise you to check out the Vuex Api Documentation to learn more about this and why you will need 'root: true'.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#vuex-store-instance-methods